# Does Timeshift Backup provide (OSD) notifications in Ubuntu?

Tags: backup, notification, notify-osd

I am trying Timeshift backup program for the first time in my Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit system. Setup and use is simple enough but I am used to Ubuntu's default program "Deja-Dup" providing persistent pop up notifications when it's time to run a scheduled backup. I've setup a scheduled backup in Timeshift, but I have not seen any notifications even though the date has already passed.

Does anyone know if Timeshift provides the same Ubuntu pop up notification (notify OSD) ?

Their website does not mention this, that I could find: http://www.teejeetech.in/p/timeshift.html

Comment: BUMP - Can anyone offer assistance?

Comment: what did you end up doing? i have the same question